# Maven maven-exec-plugin multiple execution configurations

Tags: maven-2, maven

Is it possible to invoke a maven-exec-plugin (or any other plugin's) execution by its id from the command line?

Let's say my pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<project>
[...]
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>foo</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase></phase>
            <configuration>
                <executable>echo</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>foo</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>bar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase></phase>
            <configuration>
                <executable>echo</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>bar</argument>
                </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
[...]
</project>
```

Now is it possible to call

> mvn exec:exec

with some added magic to run execution "foo"?

For the curious there is an alternative solution using profiles available here:
http://www.mail-archive.com/user@mojo.codehaus.org/msg00151.html

Comment: I cannot get the plugin to work with the <configuration> in the <execution> tag. It does however work putting it just outside the <executions> tag. The error is "The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec are missing or invalid"

Comment: Note that in the above "alternative solution using profiles", the `<plugins>` tags are missing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Executions are for binding to the lifecycle (i.e. they are not designed to be invoked on the command line). So you'll have to use the profile trick described in the link that you provided.

Comment: This isn't entirely true. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192660/maven-maven-exec-plugin-multiple-execution-configurations/7085988#7085988).

Comment: It is now possible.  See slangois's answer.

Answer (score 29):

It is now possible, starting from Maven 3.3.1: see improvement [MNG-5768](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5768) and [Maven 3.3.1 release notes](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2015/03/17/apache-maven-3-dot-3-1-features/)

You can call a specific execution configuration with this syntax:

```
mvn exec:exec@foo
```

Answer (score 11):

Not mentioned here is that, as of Maven 2.2.0, if you [give an execution of any plugin the id "default-cli"](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/configuring.html#d4e3708), then when you run that plugin from the command line, that configuration is used. You're limited to only one default execution of each plugin, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you write execute the goal:

```
org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:¿Version?:exec
```

it worked for me in eclipse maven plugin.