# How to alternate between main classes in maven exec plugin?

Tags: java, maven

I have the following pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
                <id>wizard</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <mainClass>br.com.rafa.WizardLauncher</mainClass>
                </configuration>
           </execution>
           <execution>
                <id>default-cli</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>br.com.rafa.DesktopLauncher</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

If I run `mvn exec:java`, DesktopLauncher is executed.

How can I alternate between the executions from the command line? In other words, I would like to execute WizardLauncher without changing pom.xml.

Comment: using profiles might help here, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22639106/180100)

Comment: Do I need to declare the dependencies twice (one for each profile)?

Comment: no, just keep dependencies as it is and add profiles config

Comment: it works great @RC. thanks. How do you suggest I close this question? Maybe posting my modified pom.xml?

Comment: No need to "close", the important part is that you have your answer.

Comment: You can also use `-Dexec.mainClass=` if it's unusual enough not to include an alternate in the POM.