# How to use different execution profiles with spring boot maven plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

The `exec-maven-plugin` supports setting different execution profiles [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8252214/147530)]. I'd like to use this feature e.g., to execute different main classes but I am not running the `exec-maven-plugin` directly. Instead I am executing my application using the [`spring-boot-maven-plugin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/). How can I set different execution profiles with `spring-boot-maven-plugin`?

Comment: Using `--spring-profiles.active=..` within your configuration of the exec-maven-plugin ... the question is why execution... The spring-boot-maven-plugin has a paraemter `profiles` to activate a profile (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class) article will help you.

You basically create multiple maven profiles in which you define the main class for the profile, refer to this class in the spring-boot-maven-plugin, and provide the appropriate command line options when running your application via maven.