# Maven build with multiple exec plugin executions, ant tasks

Tags: maven-3, maven-antrun-plugin, exec-maven-plugin

I have to perform following steps in my maven build, in the specific order mentioned below:

1. exec-maven-plugin
2. maven-antrun-plugin
3. exec-maven-plugin
4. maven-antrun-plugin
5. maven-remote-resources-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin
6. maven-javadoc-plugin
7. exec-maven-plugin

I have to use JDK 6, so using Maven 3.2.1.

In the pom file, I have defined 5 different profiles for #1, #2, #3, #4, #7 above (profile ids: p1, p2, p3, p4, p5).
I am building my project using multiple commands:

1. mvn exec:exec -Dp1                 (for #1 above)
2. mvn antrun:run -Dp2 exec:exec -Dp3 (for #2 and #3 above)
3. mvn antrun:run -Dp4                (for #4 above)
4. mvn clean install                  (for #5, #6 above and compile classes)
5. mvn exec:exec -Dp5                 (for #7 above)

The build works okay with multiple commands, but is it possible to execute all steps using one command i.e. mvn clean install ?

What I understand is, it is not possible to have multiple executions of exec-maven-plugin in non consecutive order, hence I used profiles and then execute each step using the profile id. Reference:
[Maven maven-exec-plugin multiple execution configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192660/maven-maven-exec-plugin-multiple-execution-configurations)

Answer (score 0):

> What I understand is, it is not possible to have multiple executions of exec-maven-plugin in non consecutive order, hence I used profiles and then execute each step using the profile id.

The “profile trick” mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2194118/6204208) is **only** needed when performing explicit goal invocation from the command line.

From what I gather, however, you would rather have your goals executed as part of a normal `mvn clean install`. In that case, you are in luck: Simply [bind each goal to an appropriate phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) in the [default lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). Depending on what your steps do, you may, e.g., bind the first `<execution>` of `exec:exec` (step 1) to the `generate-sources` phase. If the first `<execution>` of `antrun:antrun` (step 2) is then bound to, say, the `process-sources` phase, it will be called after step 1 as executes the goals bound to all phases up to `install`.

Building a project like this with a single `mvn install` is what Maven was designed to do; having to call `mvn` five times to build one project is definitely not the Maven Way.

That being said, you may run out of phases if all your steps logically belong to, say, the `package` phase. In that case, the steps are executed in the order in which their `<execution>` elements are listed in the `pom.xml`.